# Run after compiling Godot project on macOS

Tags: bash, macos, scons, godot

Want to add an admob module to the official Godot version.

When compiling the last release without any changes, following the [documentation](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/development/compiling/compiling_for_osx.html), with the command:

```
scons platform=osx arch=x86_64 --jobs=$(sysctl -n hw.logicalcpu)
```

It creates a file called godot.osx.tools.x86_64.

The mac understands .x86_64 as its file type and leaves it non executable.

The documentation assumes, that this outputted file is actually executable.

(I didn't as recommended by the doc download yarn because it's marked as OPTIONAL)

Comment: macOS doesn't interpret filenames to determine if a file is executable.. It's the permission bits on the file.  Are you sure it's not executable? type "file godot.osx.tools.x86_64" and paste the output

Comment: Hi, it is unclear what issue you are having. Edit your post and include information about what you want to do, what you have done, and what issues have arose in the process.

Answer (score 2):

You can run that file by 2 methods

1. start from terminal and run `./bin/godot.osx.tools.x86_64`
2. Follow the next step to make it an `.app` file which is documented just before section [Compiling a headless/server build](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/development/compiling/compiling_for_osx.html#compiling-a-headless-server-build)
    and open it from finder.

Comment: The binary should be made executable automatically once it's finished building. That said, I don't think Finder allows you to run those binaries by double-clicking them, so you *must* use a terminal to run them.

Comment: @Calinou you are right. Removed the chmod line. Thanks.

Comment: I have downloaded the github repository as a zip and I think it wasn't stable. at least for macOS. With the last stable release it works fine.

Thank you for the answer

Comment: You can set the answer as 'Accepted' ;-)